# "The initiated mutation process he is undergoing looks forceful WHICH PREPOSITION? him"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-verbs

What would be the most appropriate preposition in this sentence:

"The initiated mutation process is looking forceful ***PREPOSITION?*** him."

***On*** seems wrong. ***In*** seems a better fit but still a bit of a miss, too.

I do tend to use *in* but I would like some feedback, though.

**Context:** Onlookers see that a person in front of them is mutating and the process appears forceful and enforced on that person. What would be the most appropriate preposition here? This is more about how the mutation impacts the man, not how it is perceived by the onlookers.

**NOTE:** I prefer to not change the sentence, since it is a made-up sentence for a more general issue.

Comment: **To** fits, but alters your intended meaning. **On** doesn't work. Nor can I think of another preposition that does. In fact, it would do no harm to rethink the entire sentence. If he is mutating, it not a question of how things look to him, but how they feel.

Comment: "Forceful" is probably not the right word for this, regardless of the preposition. Do you mean "forced upon him", maybe?

Comment: Or do you mean that it appears to be a violent and painful experience for him?

Comment: @KateBunting -- yes, that is the intention. It appears so to the viewer but it also is an impacful and eventful process. I prefer to not change the sentence, since it is a made-up sentence for a more general issue.

Comment: The problem is that _forceful_ normally describes the way something is done, not the way the victim experiences it.

Comment: Okay, thank you. If you want, you can change the adjective, so that it is more correct. However, I'm more interested in the preposition. The sentence is tricky but not incorrect.

Comment: But often the choice of preposition depends _entirely_ on the particular word chosen. _He was desirous of/interested in meeting you_. There is not necessarily a "general issue" that you can identify.

Comment: @ColinFine -- exactly, that is why I have asked this question.

Comment: But there isn't an answer to the specific question, because _forceful_ isn't used in that way, so nobody knows which preposition it might govern.

Comment: @ColinFine -- in this case, the proposition depends on the verb, not the adjective. As said in an earlier comment, you can replace forceful with

Comment: @ColinFine -- the proposition depends on the verb and thr intention of what one wants to say, not on the adjective. You can replace 'forceful' with 'violent', which still leaves the question for the most appropriate preposition unanswered.

Comment: Why should the preposition depend on the verb? You are using it (if I understand your intention correctly) to denote the target of the violence, not the object of looking. So I stand by my comments that the appropriate preposition would depend on what _forceful_ required, but _forceful_ is not used in that construction. Nor is _violent_.

Comment: Actually, I partly take that back - either _forceful_ or _violent_ could be used there, with preposition _towards_.